# Is \x->y alpha equivalent to \y->y?

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus

Is `\x->y` alpha equivalent to `\y->y` ? Please help Im really confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, they are not alpha equivalent**

`λx.y` has a free variable `y` and a bound variable `x` – this is *constant* y

`λy.y` has *no* free variables and one bound variable `y` – this is also known as the *identity function*